# Expectation of distance of two points with uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, uniform-distribution

A circle with radius $a$, and two points $A, B$ on the disk are chosen independently and follow uniform distribution. Setting the distance of $\overline{AB} = R$

Now I would like to find the expectation of $R^2$. First, I think the distribution will be like $A \sim B \sim U[0, a^2π]$. Yet, I have no much thought about connecting the distance $R$ with expectation.

To me, it probablity looks like this $E[R^2] = \int_0^{a^2π}x^2f(x)dx$, in this case, what should I replace with $f(x)$ to stand for $R^2$?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are uniform in the cicle ?

Comment: Yes, in the circle. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: Do you mean the circle (the 1D border) of the disk (which is 2D).

Comment: The OP is fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are uniformly and independently distributed on the disk centered at origin and of radius $a$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[R^2] &= \mathbb E[(A_1-B_1)^2+(A_2-B_2)^2]\\
&= \mathbb E[A_1^2 - 2 A_1 B_1 + B_1^2 + A_2^2 - 2 A_2 B_2 + B_2^2]\\
&=4\mathbb E[A_1^2]-4\mathbb E[A_1]\cdot \mathbb E [B_1]\\
&=4 \mathbb E[A_1^2]\\
&=2\mathbb E[A_1^2+A_2^2]
\end{align*}
because $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ all have the same distribution with $0$ average, $A_1$ and $B_1$ are independent as well as $A_2$ and $B_2$.

Now $A_1^2+A_2^2$ is just the square of the distance of $A$ to $0$, it can be computing by integrating
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[A_1^2+A_2^2] &= \int_{\mathbf x\in C_a} \frac{1}{\pi a^2}(x_1^2+x_2^2) ~d\mathbf x\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a \frac{1}{\pi a^2} r^2\cdot r ~dr d\theta\\
&=\left[ \frac{r^4}{2a^2} \right]_0^a\\
&=\frac{a^2}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore $\mathbb E[R^2]=a^2$.